# How to query Issues updated by membersOf("TEAMX") on Yesterday in JQL

Tags: jira, jql

I want to create a filter to check the issues that my team members has worked on  yesterday. How can I do that. I treid this.

```
watcher in membersOf("TEAMX") AND updatedDate < -1d AND updatedDate > -2d ORDER BY updatedDate asc
```

But it gives an issue watched by member of TEAMX (in any date) but updated o yesterday but any one. (maybe not in TEAMX).

My actual concern is creating a filter for query the TEAMX members that haven't enter worklog yesterday. Above one is just a secondary option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the free [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin installed, you have a lot of JQL functions added. One of it is the [workLogged](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-workLogged(worklogquery)) (The link in that sentence points [here](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-commented(commentquery))).

#### Cons

1. It accepts only a username, **not groups**, nor roles.
2. JIRA needs to be reindexed after plugin installation to use this function.

#### Usage

- `issueFunction in workLogged("by johndoe after 2015/01/01")`
- `project = PRJX AND issueFunction in workLogged("on -1d")`

Comment: Thank you Koshinae! I'll check on this.